# Converting YYYY-MM-DD to unix timestamp in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert a date in format eg. 2011-01-02 to a unix timestamp in JavaScript but do not exactly know how to accomplish it. I can get the current timestamp using the following functions `Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);` but do not know how to convert the given date to a unix timestamp?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can write `new Date("2011-01-02").getTime() / 1000`

Comment: Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Noting that "2011-01-02" will be parsed as UTC, not local as may be expected by those familiar with ISO 8601 but not ECMA-262. ;-)

Comment: Im here because I can't find a way to get YYYY-MM-DD into a locally correct timestamp....